# Excel VBA: Error in colouring the bar in barchart according to their value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a chart with many series. And I want to colour all the bar in the chart (all series) with red if it has value<100 and with green if it has value>=100. My code is

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim chartIterator As Integer, pointIterator As Integer, seriescollectionIterator As Integer, _
    seriesArray() As Variant

    For chartIterator = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
        For seriescollectionIterator = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
            seriesArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator).Chart.SeriesCollection(seriescollectionIterator).Values

                For pointIterator = 1 To UBound(seriesArray)

                    If seriesArray(pointIterator) >= 5 Then
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
                        Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
                        RGB(146, 208, 80)
                    Else
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
                        Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
                        RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    End If


                Next pointIterator
        Next seriescollectionIterator
    Next chartIterator

End Sub
```

The problem is this works for first series alone. I debugged. Though the seriescollectionIterator updates, nothing happens. Please help me to rectify this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle part refers specifically to `SeriesCollection(1)` - you need:

```
               If seriesArray(pointIterator) >= 5 Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
                    Chart.SeriesCollection(seriescollectionIterator).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
                    RGB(146, 208, 80)
                Else
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
                    Chart.SeriesCollection(seriescollectionIterator).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
                    RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
```

Comment: yeahh... my carelessness.. Thank you so much